# Descobrir chave de uma array pelo valor dado?

Tags: php

Gostaria que através de um valor dado eu pudesse retornar a chave do array. Exemplo:

```
$array = array("primeiro" => 1, "segundo" => 2, "terceiro" => 3);
```

para descobrir se o valor existe no array existe a função `in_array();` mas e para descobrir a chave do array a qual aquele valor pertence? como posso fazer isso de uma forma simples? utilizando o exemplo dado, através do valor dado '1', descobrir a chave "primeiro".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize a função [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), dado um valor se encontrado ele retorna a chave correspondente do array.

[demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/aqtm-knsr)

```
<?php
$arr = array("primeiro" => 1, "segundo" => 2, "terceiro" => 3);
$chave = array_search('1', $arr);

echo $chave;
```

Saida:

```
primeiro
```